# apparently apache retrieves index.php from non existent directory

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a web site defined in apache2 with the conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my.site.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foto
    <Directory /var/www/foto>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is fine, but:

- If I load `my.site.net/non-existent-directory` (without the trailing slash), the `/var/www/foto/index.php` file is loaded, and all the files which are loaded by index.php are found

Why is `/var/www/foto/index.php` loaded? I'd expect a not found error.

How is `non-existent-directory` interpreted?

- if I load `my.site.net/non-existent-directory/` (with the trailing slash), the `/var/www/foto/index.php` file is loaded, Loading it, the files which should be loaded by index.php are not found, because are searched in the non existent directory.

Again, why is `/var/www/foto/index.php` loaded?

What should I do in order to avoid it?

**Edit**: removed trailing slash from DocumentRoot and upgraded `order allow,deny, allow from all` to `Require all granted`

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess file in /var/www/foto?

Comment: The  .htaccess file is not relevant, `AllowOverride None` in vhost prevents them to be loaded. From doc, *The `DocumentRoot` should be specified* ***without a trailing slash***. I would try first to remove the trailing slash. Also note the `order allow,deny, allow from all` directives are apache2.2 synthaxe. You should try to use [the apache2.4 synthaxe](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/howto/access.html) (`Require all granted`)

Comment: removed the trailing slash, nothing changed